# How to make <br> working even there is htmlspecialchars function

Tags: php, html

Hi is there any way to make `<br>` working even there is `htmlspecialchars` function.
My problem is when i put a text inside the function `htmlspecialchars` there be no new lines even the text has new lines.
My code is like:

```
$text_val = "
this is a line
it is a new line
one more line
";

$final_text = str_replace("\n","<br>",$text_val);

$text = htmlspecialchars($final_text);
echo $text;
```

and result is like:

```
this is a line it is a new line one more line
```

But i want it like the first:

```
this is a line
it is a new line
one more line
```

thank you guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use built in PHP function **nl2br** `$final_text = nl2br($text_val);`

Comment: it worked for me but with nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text_val))

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `htmlspecialchars_decode()` function but using the `htmlspecialchars()` function instead.

Replace this line:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($final_text);
```

with this:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars_decode($final_text);
```